# jQuery Plugin Interfering W/ Other Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

So I am using a plugin that creates a vertical paging animation.

It basically makes a fullscreen box and moves the "sections" through this box.

Here is the html to help show what I mean.

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

I had a simple javascript function to hide my nav whenever you scroll down. The problem is, with this new plugin, you don't actually scroll down. Sections just move inside a stationary box.

Here is the javascript function I was using for the nav.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > 0) {

        $('#navBar').addClass('scroll');
    } 
    else{

        $('#navBar').removeClass('scroll');
    }
});
```

So the `y > 0` doesn't trigger with this plugin anymore so the nav won't hide properly.

I'm thinking there has to be a way to change this simple code a little and make it work. Maybe by using IDs inside the sections possibly?

Here is how my html looks with the general structure from the plugin applied.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aldi Rebrand</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="red">
        <div id="navBar" class="preHidden">
            <a href="index.html"><img id="navLogo" src="images/navLogo.png"></a>
            <ul>
                <li class = "navLink mainLink"><a href="index.html">Work</a></li>
                <li class = "navLink mainLink"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class = "navLink mainLink"><a href="https://ggann.tumblr.com">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <div id="fullpage">
                <div class="section">
                    <div id="aldiPhoto"></div>
                    <div id="descriptionAldi">
                        <h2>ALDI Rebrand <span>BRANDING | LOGO | PRINT</span></h2>
                        <p class="intro"><strong>ALDI</strong> is an international grocer, spanning from Germany to The United States and many other countries around the world.</p>
                        <p class="prjctDescription">The premise behind this semester long project was to immerse ourselves in the company/brand we were assigned. I was assigned ALDI. In this scenario, the goal of the rebrand was to convey a new “fresh and local” side to ALDI and their proposed farmers market addition to their stores. We were asked to create a brand new logo, at least four pieces of collateral and a brand guideline to demonstrate our research, branding applications and flexibility.</p>
                        <div class="btnDiv">
                            <a href="https://dribbble.com/shots/1869394-ALDI-Rebrand" class="btnText"><div class="btn1"><p>VIEW ON DRIBBBLE</p></div></a>
                            <a href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/22556203/ALDI-Rebrand" class="btnText"><div class="btn2"><p>VIEW ON BEHANCE</p></div></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <div id="aldiPage2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <div id="aldiPage3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ticker"><p class="currentPage">1</p><div class="tickerBtm"><p class="maxPage">3</p></div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is a jsfiddle of this page: https://jsfiddle.net/L0h1uxLo/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`onLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction) event to get the scrolled index value and toggle the class `scroll`.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        onLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) {
            //console.log(index);
            if (index > 1) {
                $('#navBar').addClass('scroll');
            } else {
                $('#navBar').removeClass('scroll');

            }
        }
    });
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L0h1uxLo/2/)

Comment: It seems that the fiddle works exactly how I want, but I cannot get it to work in my code. When I leave the line $('#fullpage').fullpage(); and add the code you use in the fiddle demo, the nav bar doesn't hide and the scrolling javascript skips all the sections and scrolls to the last one. If I remove $('#fullpage').fullpage(); and put your code in, the scrolling won't work anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to remove code and replace it with mine. Strange its not working for you. Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: I just copied the entire javascript that you have in the fiddle and I must have made a mistake when I was typing it up myself because what you have works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Know how I could make the numbers at the bottom left of my page show the values of the current page or "section" in the top box and the max pages or "sections" in the bottomw box? haha

Comment: @Ed117 I have used index for the boxes. Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0h1uxLo/3/)

Comment: Most plugins expose events for all such calculations. Glad to know it helped :)